# Magento 2 : Is there a way to query products using Custom Attributes in Rest API Call?

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection, custom-attributes, rest-api

I have a custom attribute setup for Books called **isbn_13**

Now I try to find the products using the isbn_13 values but unable to filter the results based on this. Is there any way to do this?

Update: I am trying to do this via RestAPI

Here is the rest URL I have used while querying:

```
https://www.mysite.in/rest/all/V1/products/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=attribute_code&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=isbn_13&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=ASC&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1
```

Somehow I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Answer (score 10):

Resolved the issue by directly using the attribute_code within the search criteria.

```
https://{domain}/rest/all/V1/products/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=isbn_13&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=9780874810417
```

It finally returned the result.